# Vim open file at location that was last viewed

Tags: unix, vim

When I close a file in vim and reopen it, the file opens at the start of the file.  Is there anyway to make the file open at the last place the I viewed?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I just noticed that my cursor has started to have this behavior.  I went through my vimrc (commenting out line by line) and found that this code will also work:

```
"make vim save and load the folding of the document each time it loads"
"also places the cursor in the last place that it was left."
au BufWinLeave * mkview
au BufWinEnter * silent loadview
```

*(Quotes finished to make it easier to read)*

The main purpose of this block is to make any folds created appear again when a file is opened but apparently it also saves/loads the cursor position.

Comment: Hint: In neovim one needs to end `silent!` with an exclamation mark as `:help loadview` suggests.

Answer (score 10):

Put this in your `.vimrc` :

```
if has("autocmd")
  " When editing a file, always jump to the last cursor position
  autocmd BufReadPost *
  \ if line("'\"") > 0 && line ("'\"") X= line("$") |
  \   exe "normal g'\"" |
  \ endif
endif
```

Just change the big X with `<`.

If I put `<` the code fails to print correctly.

Comment: +1. As a BTW, you can read more on this from :help last-position-jump.

Comment: Also, this command ('") is not available in vi, which might be why sixtyfootersdude's vi is not behaving like this by default.  It's the default behavior in vim.

Comment: +1: Thanks for the response but I think that I found a simpler solution (by mistake)

Comment: this is the same answer as given here: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/23335/how-to-open-a-file-in-the-last-closed-position-in-vi

Answer (score 2):

There is a plugin called [vim-lastplace](https://github.com/dietsche/vim-lastplace) (I am the author) that will open your files where you left off. It improves on the above suggestions by ignoring commit messages because you're typically editing a new message and want to start at the top of the commit message file.

Comment: Hi Greg, regarding your last answers, please take a look [here](http://superuser.com/help/promotion).

Comment: I think its Greg is doing okay so far. Still he must go through the link you shared

Comment: I think my answer is both good and relevant. I disclosed that I am the author. Is there something I've missed? From the policy: "Post good, relevant answers, and if some (but not all) happen to be about your product or website, that’s okay. However, you must disclose your affiliation in your answers."